Is there a verb for "to do something that was forgotten"?
I'm looking for a verb that describes the action of "to do something that was forgotten".
For example:

A student who was asked to bring a document to his teacher today but he forgot, so he'll have do it tomorrow.

Is there a dedicated verb for this kind of action?

There are terms such as catch-up (noun, verb, etc) for work that's making up for other work that wasn't submitted on time, but I doubt there's a term specific to when you forgot to do it (as opposed to not doing it because you were too busy, sick, couldn't be bothered, ran out of time, etc). Also, by "document" do you mean an assignment/essay/paper/dissertation/project, or something else (like I don't know, a sick note, a certificate showing completion of work, evidence of funding, a proposal, permission slip, etc???)

OP has asked:

A student who was asked to bring a document to his teacher today but forgot, so he'll have to do it tomorrow. Is there a dedicated verb for this kind of action?

There isn’t a single verb to describe this action, but the following sentences convey the idea effectively:

"He will have to make amends for forgetting and bring the document tomorrow."
"He will need to bring the document tomorrow to make up for his forgetfulness."
"To correct the oversight, he has to bring the document tomorrow."
"He will have to make up for his forgetfulness by delivering the document tomorrow."


A student was asked to bring a document to his teacher today but he forgot, so he'll have to do it tomorrow.

A student was asked to bring a document to his teacher today but he forgot, so he'll have to rectify that tomorrow. [formal]

A student was asked to bring a document to his teacher today but he forgot, so he'll have to remedy that tomorrow. [formal]

A student was asked to bring a document to his teacher today but he forgot, so he'll have to fix that tomorrow. [somewhat informal]


Merriam Webster synonyms
